# How can I wrap this into Scaffold in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to wrap this widget inside a Scaffold in order to include some title text for my app. However it returns an empty screen when I wrap it with Scaffold. Why is that?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: Dimensions.pageView,
          child: PageView.builder(
              //depende de dos parámetros el builder. Position cogerá desde el index 0 al itemcount.
              itemCount: items.length,
              controller: pageController,
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                return _buildPageItem(position);
              }),
        ),
        

       ... MORE BASIC CHILDRENS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Title'),
    ),
    body: Column(
    .....
    ),
  );
}
```

**Note that you don't need SafeArea when using AppBar**